# tunctl similar command for OS X

Tags: macos, networking, tun

Is there any command to create, delete, etc `tun` / `tap` devices in OS X, like [`tunctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tunctl) in Linux?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to install [TunTap](http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/), it's a TUN/TAP driver for OS X.

The TunTap package is comprised of a pair of kernel extensions, one providing tun and one providing tap interfaces. They create a set of character devices `/dev/tunX` and `/dev/tapX`, respectively, where X is a number between zero and the maximum number of supported virtual interfaces.

For example, to use `tap0`:

- `open()` the character device `/dev/tap0`. Usually tun/tap network interfaces are created on demand when a program opens the associated character device. But for testing, you can do `exec 5<>/dev/tap0` from a root shell to open the `tap0` character device on shell file descriptor 5.
- Configure the `tap0` network interface, `ifconfig tap0 10.1.2.3 up`.
- Now you can use `read()` and `write()` to send or receive packets.
- `close()` the character device when you're done.

Comment: I already have the kernel extensions installed. As the subject says, I'm searching for a command that does what `tunctl` does on Linux. Or, for that matter, some sort of workaround.

Comment: Well the 'workaround' is what I put in my example. It's not super involved, just a few commands. `tunctl -u user` would essentially be `sudo sh -c "exec 5<>/dev/tap0;chown user:user /dev/tap0"`